# How can I trigger a function anytime there is a new session in a GAE/Python Application?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am a newbie to Google App Engine and Python.

I want to create an entry in a SessionSupplemental table (Kind) anytime a new user accesses the site (regardless of what page they access initially).

How can I do this?

I can imagine that there is a list of standard event triggers in GAE; where would I find these documented?  I can also imagine that there are a lot of system/application attributes; where can I find these documented and how to use them?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't completely address your question (as it refers to 'users'  in the Google Account sense), but there is a Users service (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) provided by GAE. Again, this is Google-account specific, but it could serve as a model of how to set up your system (I think an issue will be how to identify non-logged-in users as 'new', an area in which I have 0 knowledge :) ).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to be pretty general here as I don't know whether you are using the default users service or not and I don't know how you are uniquely linking your SessionSupplemental entities to users or whether you even have a way to identify users at this point. I am also assuming you are using some version of webapp as that is the standard request handling library on App Engine. Let me know a bit more and I can update the answer to be more specific.

- Subclass the default RequestHandler in webapp with a new class (such as MyRequestHandler).
- In your subclass override the initialize() method.
- In your new initialize() method get the current user from your session system (or the users service or whatever you are using). Test to see if a SessionSupplemental entity already exists for this user and if not create a new one.
- For all your other request handlers you now want to subclass MyRequestHandler (instead of the default RequestHandler).
- Whenever a request happens webapp will automatically call the initialize() method.
- This is going to cost you a read for every request and also a write for every request by a new user. If you use the ndb library (instead of db) then a lot of the requests will just hit memcache instead of the datastore.

Now if you are just starting creating a new AppEngine app I would recommend using the Python27 runtime and webapp2 and trying to leverage as much of the webapp2 Auth module as you can so you don't have to write so much session stuff yourself. Also, ndb can be much nicer than the default db library.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I am already using webapp2, Pyhton2.7 and ndb.  I will try to research Auth.  In the past I have tried to ask where I could get a lit of modules that one could just add and use (similar to those in Drupal or DotNetNuke) and I don't seem to get any answers.  I have build frameworks of my own in other environments (Windows/IIS) to include session management, authorization and role and permission management, etc. but I am finding it difficult to do the same in GAE/Python.  Maybe Auth will give me some ideas.

Comment: Take a look at the various webapp2_extras (http://webapp-improved.appspot.com). The Sessions module in there might be useful to you as well. If you are looking for something like Drupal or DotNetNuke you can probably find an existing Python CMS (http://stackoverflow.com/q/184742/98138) but I am not familiar with any of them. If all you are looking for is sessions, auth, and roles/permissions then I recommend leveraging webapp2 extras or finding an alternative to webapp2 that has what you need. Pylons and Django are worth looking at.